# String conversion from Utf8

Tags: java, string, utf-8

```
   record.get("key")
```

Here, `record` is `org.apache.avro.GenericReord`. In my case it returns `utf8`. I need String. So possibilities I found

```
   record.get("key").toString() - I prefer cast than this method
   record.get("key")+""         - It calls string concatenation method
```

The above two works.

```
   (String)record.get("key") - Obviously it throws a classcastexception.
   new String(record.get("key")) - new String(Object) is undefined.
```

The above two doesn't work.

My doubt is which one is better in terms of performance `toString()` and `+` in my scenario.

Comment: The big question is not, what `record` is, but what `record.get("key");` returns. You get an Object, but what type exactly? Obviously it's not a String, otherwise your cast would work. Find out what it is, for example by `Object o = record.get("key"); System.out.println( o.getClass().getName() );` (or simpler, look at/post the ClassCastException). Unless you know what type ist always is, you don't have much choice besides `toString()`. Oh, and btw.: Your second try also just calles toString, just implicitly.

Comment: The second one is same as: `record.get("key").toString()+""`, which in turn should be using StringBuilder to build the string. So, the first one should be better.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz I have told conversion from utf8. So it returns utf8. In the question I mentioned record is `GenericRecord`. What is your doubt?

Comment: `toString()` is the idiomatic choice and much more readable. You should worry about performance in this case only if you can identify this piece of code as a bottleneck in your application (which it probably isn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have another option which **String.valueOf(record.get("key"))** Dont use record.get("key").toString() directly because there might be change of getting NullPointerException.

Approch difference

`record.get("key")+""` uses StringBuilder to create resultant String whereas

`String.valueOf(record.get("key"))`  invokes simply a static method of String to get the String version of object

Comment: Yes. I faced this issue. `valuOf` returns "null" if result is null.Otherwise it is same as `toString()`

Answer (score 0):

the `toString()` works better.

when you are using `+` operator it will compare the type of two Objects to perform the operation. ex. if it's both type of a Number it will adds the two but if it's with different type it will simply call the `toString()` of an object and concat the strings.

chance of getting NullPointerException with `toString()` is high. 
You might want to use `String.valueOf(record.get("key"))`